# Why am I not able to select above a certain language level in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: maximum language level I can set is 9 under project structure]I'm running IntelliJ with JDK 11, but it won't let me select higher than 9 for project language level. What is going on here?

Development -- Looks like in the "About" Section under IntelliJ IDEA, my JRE is 1.8...how can I modify this?

[image: JRE is 1.8 here]

Comment: can you show how you're currently doing it?

Comment: Give screenshot, but not sure you could help

Comment: Screenshot added

Comment: What is your intelliJ version ? `Help -> About`

Comment: IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your Intellij Version, `2017.3.5` does not support project level higher than 9

- Support Java 11 : [*IntelliJ 2018.2*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2018-2)
- Support Java 12 : [*IntelliJ 2018.3*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2018-3)

Update from : [Download IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html#section=windows)